# Sub procedure or function procedure not defined error

Tags: vba, excel, range, worksheet

Good morning, I try to  insert data in a excel sheet with macro in VBA.
I have read lot of tutorial, but I don't understand some methods does not work (like Range).
My macro :

```
Sub Main()

Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
FolderPath = "C:\Users\Victor\Documents\Algorithme et JS"
count = 0
path = FolderPath & "\*.docx"

Filename = Dir(path)

Do While Filename <> ""
   Filename = Dir()
   count = count + 1
Loop

MsgBox count
Workbook("Sheet1.xlsx").Worksheets("Feuille1").Range("A1").Value = count

End Sub
```

So this macro return me the answer "7" (I have seven .docx in my folder) with the line "MsgBox count", however the last line does not work, and return me "Sub procedure or function procedure not defined."
Seriously I do not understand, when I read tutorial they arrive to do this so easily...
I have forgot something in my macro ?

PS : Sorry for my english, it is not my mother tongue.

Comment: change `Workbook` to `Workbooks`. It's just a typo

Comment: Sorry but I have the same error =/

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `workbook` line? Are you trying to insert the value in the current workbook or a closed workbook?

Comment: I try with a closed workbook. I tried with a current workbook but it do not work too.

Comment: Is this code within the workbook Sheet1.xlsx? If not is that workbook open?

Comment: My workbook Sheet1.xlsx is close. His location is "C:\Users\Victor\Documents\Algorithme et JS", like the .docx I find.

Comment: You can't update the value of a closed workbook like this...Maybe [THIS CAN HELP](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/various-ways-to-pull-data-from-another-workbook-closedopened/)

Comment: It is problematic, I forgot to say I use LibreOffice, and i can't save in .xlsm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to open Sheet1.xlsx before you can update the value of that cell. Short example of how to do this below:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Victor\Documents\Algorithme et JS\Sheet1.xlsx")
wb.Worksheets("Feuille1").Range("A1").Value = Count
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: The first line do not work, "The type of data Workbook is unknow". I forgot to say I use LibreOffice, it is a problem ?

Comment: I've tested the answer on my own computer using Microsoft Excel. Whether or not the solution also works in LibreOffice I can't know as I don't use it and you didn't specify in your question that this was the case. It might be worth noting that using the [excel] and [vba] tags in this case could be considered misleading.

Comment: Don't worry, I install Microsoft Excel, I think it will be more easily.

Comment: Lot of thanks, I think all my problems come to LibreOffice, my code and your solution run without problem with Microsoft Office.